# Why doesn't my bounty show up by default?

Tags: support, bounty

I have posted a bounty on a question. It does not show up:

[image]

But if I click on the "complete list" link, it adds it to the list.  It is not like we are overrun with bounty questions, so why isn't it showing up on the primary list?  Is there something I needed to do to make it show up?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Should I blame caching?](https://shouldiblamecaching.com/)

To avoid heavy load on the servers, question lists are cached. I'm not sure what the cache time is, it might depend on the site, but [this answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/183148/295232) suggests it's a minute or so.